# Backbone.js and REST api with Silex (PHP)

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js, silex

lets say I have a model called John with those params:

```
{
    Language : {
        code    :  'gr',
        title   :  'Greek'
    },
    Name : 'john'
}
```

So now when I trigger `John.save()` it POST those to server:

[post params http://o7.no/ypvWNp](http://o7.no/ypvWNp)

with those headers:

[headers http://o7.no/x5DVw0](http://o7.no/x5DVw0)

The code in Silex is really simple:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar';

$app = new Silex\Application();

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// definitions
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->post('/api/user', function (Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->get('Name'));

    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    var_dump($params->Name);
});

$app->run();
```

but first `var_dump` return null second var_dump of course works since I'm getting the request directly from `php://input` resource. I'm wondering how I could get the params using Request object from Silex

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request = new ParameterBag(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});
```

And then an example route:

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->get('foo');
});
```

And testing with curl:

```
$ curl http://localhost/foobarbazapp/app.php -d '{"foo": "bar"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
bar
$
```

Alternatively look at the (slightly outdated) [RestServiceProvider](https://github.com/flintstones/Rest).

EDIT: I have turned this answer into a [cookbook recipe in the silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot! That was a solution! Although I believe Silex should take care it by default without a need to add a `before` filter. Regarding the content type, `$request->headers->get('Content-Type')` returns `application/json; charset=UTF-8` so I would prefer to check like that: `if ('application/json' === strstr($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), ';', true))` or to be more bulletproof like that: `if (false !== strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json'))`

Comment: `0 === strpos(` even, will adjust my answer.

Comment: From php manual: `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "".` so I tend to use false instead of 0 :)

Comment: if you want to check if _b_ exists in _abc_ with `0 === strpos` you'll get false but it won't be the case for example: `0 === strpos('abc', 'b')` returns false `0 === strpos('abc', 'a')` will return true so the best way to go is `false !== strpos('abc', 'b')` to be bulletproof

Comment: I want to check if it begins with `application/json`.

Comment: yes in this case `0 === strpos` will work I spoke generally sorry! :) Still thanks for the reply, you saved my day! :) but still I believe it should be out of the box by Silex :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6406/discussion-between-igorw-and-panosru)

Comment: you could check as well that it is an ajax request: $request->isXmlHttpRequest()

Answer (score 4):

The way I have done it before is the following:

```
$app->post('/api/todos', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->create();
    $todo->title = $data->title;
    $todo->save();

    return new Response(json_encode($todo->as_array()), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
});
```

In your backbone collection, add the following:

```
window.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,

    url: "api/todos",

    ...
});
```

I have written up a full step-by-step tutorial here http://cambridgesoftware.co.uk/blog/item/59-backbonejs-%20-php-with-silex-microframework-%20-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself by setting an extra `$payload` property on the Request object

```
$app->before(function(Request $request) {
    if (stristr($request->getContentType(), 'json')) {
        $data             = json_decode($request->getContent());
        $request->payload = $data;
    } else {
        $request->payload = null;
    }
});
```